# scipy optimize.curve_fit cannot fit a function whose return value depends on a conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I want to fit a function, defined as follows, to a time series data:

```
def func(t, a0, a1, a2, T, tau1, tau2):
    if t < T:
        return a0 + a1 * np.exp(-t/tau1) + a2 * np.exp(-t/tau2)
    else:
        return a0 + a1 * np.exp(-T/tau1) * (1 - t/tau1 + T/tau1) + a2 * np.exp(-T/tau2) * (1 - t/tau2 + T/tau2)
```

Here, t represents the time at which a measurement is made, and the rest of the arguments are the parameters of the function. The problem is that when I feed it into curve_fit, Python complains about the ambiguity in the t < T comparison. I believe this happens because t becomes a list of data points when func is called inside curve_fit, whereas T is a number (not a list):

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t1, d1)
```

where t1 is a list of times and d1 is a list of the data values measured at the corresponding times. I have attempted a number of ways to get around this problem, but to no avail. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's right, `t < T` is a boolean array. NumPy refuses to assign a truth value to boolean arrays because there are many possible choices -- should it be True if *all* elements are True, or if *any* element is True?

But that's okay. In this case, NumPy provides a nice function to replace the `if ... else ...` blocks, namely, [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def func(t, a0, a1, a2, T, tau1, tau2):
    return np.where(
        t < T,
        a0 + a1 * np.exp(-t/tau1) + a2 * np.exp(-t/tau2),
        a0 + a1 * np.exp(-T/tau1) * (1 - t/tau1 + T/tau1) + a2 * np.exp(-T/tau2) * (1 - t/tau2 + T/tau2) )
```

Comment: `T` doesn't converge.