# scipy.optimize.curve_fit with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm using the Python + NumPy + SciPy to determine the coefficients of the equation based on data. The equation is defined as follows:

```
def func (x, a,b,c,d):
    if x < d:
        return 0
    else:
        return a * ( 1 - np.exp( - b * (x - c) ** d)
```

From what I've found the traditional representation of function will not work according to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314699/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-cannot-fit-a-function-whose-return-value-depends-on-a-c) and must be replaced by :

```
def func (x, a,b,c,d):
    return np.where ( x < c,
        0 ,
        a * ( 1 - np.exp( - b * (x - c) ** d) )
    )
```

This one raises the error `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power a * ( 1 - np.exp( - b * (x - c) ** d)`.

From what I understand it happens because of an attempt to create 2 arrays of numbers (in this case):

- the first one filled with 0
- the second one filled with results of `a * ( 1 - np.exp( - b * (x - c) ** d) )`

And then, create the resulting array based on the conditional selection of those two.
Creation of the second array in interval `x < c` in some combination with fractional values of `d` results in taking roots from negative numbers. And this causes the problem.

My workaround for this is:

```
def func (x, a,b,c,d):
    return np.where ( x < c,
        0 ,
        a * ( 1 - np.exp( - b * np.abs( x - c) ** d) )
    )
```

It works fine, since the range of values where `x < c` is defined by condition, 
but is there a better way to do it?

Ideally,  which even prevents the calculation `a * ( 1 - np.exp( - b * (x - c) ** d)` if `x < c` and unversal, make is aplicable for larger number of conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem completely:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html