# TypeError when using scipy.optimize.curve_fit with a piecewise function using piecewise functions

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a [q-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Gaussian_distribution#Probability_density_function) to my data using the `curve_fit` function from the `scipy.optimize` library.
Since I didn't find any implementation of q-Gaussians in scipy I wrote it myself:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import gamma

def qGauss(x, q, beta):
    # needs q < 3 and beta > 0    
    return np.sqrt(beta) / const(q) * np.array([e(q, - beta * xk**2) for xk in x])
    # return np.sqrt(beta) / const(q) * e(q, - beta * x**2)

def const(q):
    if q < 1:
        return 2 * np.sqrt(np.pi) * gamma(1/(1 - q)) / ((3 - q) * np.sqrt(1 - q) * gamma((3-q)/(2*(1-q))))
    if q == 1:
        return np.sqrt(np.pi)
    if 1 < q < 3:
        return np.sqrt(np.pi) * gamma((3-q)/(2*(q-1))) / ( np.sqrt(q-1) * gamma(1/(q - 1)))
    if q >= 3:
        return 100000000000
 
def e(q, y):
    if q == 1:
        return np.exp(y)
    else:     
        return (relu(1 + (1 - q) * y))**(1/(1 - q))
    
def relu(x):
    return 1/2 * (x + np.abs(x))
```

I have an array `x` which is like a `np.linspace(-15,15, 200)` and an array `last` of values of my function to which I want to fit my q-Gaussian.
Hence I write

```
q, beta = curve_fit(qGauss, x, last)[0]
```

The error I get is

> 29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
> return np.sqrt(np.pi) * gamma((3-q)/(2*(q-1))) / ( np.sqrt(q-1) * gamma(1/(q - 1)))
> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\vglom\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
> File "c:\users\vglom\downloads\renyi flow\entropy_flow.py", line 127, in 
> q, beta = curve_fit(qGauss, x, last)[0]

> File "C:\Users\vglom\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minpack_py.py", line 859, in curve_fit
> res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\vglom\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minpack_py.py", line 426, in leastsq
> retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,

> File "C:\Users\vglom\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minpack_py.py", line 501, in func_wrapped
> return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

> File "c:\users\vglom\downloads\renyi flow\entropy_flow.py", line 20, in qGauss
> return np.sqrt(beta) / const(q) * np.array([e(q, - beta * xk**2) for xk in x])

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'NoneType'

By @NickO'Dell 's comment I realized that the error is due to `const` only being defined for q < 3.
What value could I prescribe for q >= 3? I think that any q >= 3 would be ignored as potential best fit parameter if the corresponding function would be zero. But setting const(q) = 10000000 does not alleviate the error.
Maybe specifying an initial guess for curve_fit which is sufficiently lower than 3 can help?

I have consulted [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707419/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-with-conditions), which suggests to use `np.piecewise`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use this since my function is build from multiple functions which each are piecewise.

---

The values I am trying are e.g

```
x = array([-14.7, -14.1, -13.5, -12.9, -12.3, -11.7, -11.1, -10.5,  -9.9,
        -9.3,  -8.7,  -8.1,  -7.5,  -6.9,  -6.3,  -5.7,  -5.1,  -4.5,
        -3.9,  -3.3,  -2.7,  -2.1,  -1.5,  -0.9,  -0.3,   0.3,   0.9,
         1.5,   2.1,   2.7,   3.3,   3.9,   4.5,   5.1,   5.7,   6.3,
         6.9,   7.5,   8.1,   8.7,   9.3,   9.9,  10.5,  11.1,  11.7,
        12.3,  12.9,  13.5,  14.1,  14.7])
```

and

```
last = array([3.75486439e-31, 3.51232052e-28, 6.47456074e-16, 1.96076672e-08,
       7.44254728e-05, 2.99305062e-03, 1.14129158e-02, 1.59441135e-02,
       2.09097679e-02, 2.62174029e-02, 3.01809751e-02, 3.47127577e-02,
       3.83598231e-02, 4.20004848e-02, 4.52268881e-02, 4.81646244e-02,
       5.08229316e-02, 5.31691166e-02, 5.52105374e-02, 5.69888249e-02,
       5.84228125e-02, 5.96213766e-02, 6.04707469e-02, 6.10742404e-02,
       6.13554974e-02, 6.13554974e-02, 6.10742404e-02, 6.04707469e-02,
       5.96213766e-02, 5.84228125e-02, 5.69888249e-02, 5.52105374e-02,
       5.31691166e-02, 5.08229316e-02, 4.81646244e-02, 4.52268881e-02,
       4.20004848e-02, 3.83598231e-02, 3.47127577e-02, 3.01809751e-02,
       2.62174029e-02, 2.09097679e-02, 1.59441135e-02, 1.14129158e-02,
       2.99305062e-03, 7.44254728e-05, 1.96076672e-08, 6.47456074e-16,
       3.51232052e-28, 3.75486439e-31])
```

Answer (score 0):

I specified the initial guess q = 0.5 and beta = 0.1 like this

```
q, beta = curve_fit(qGauss, x, last, p0 = [0.5, 0.1])[0]
```

then the curve fitting worked well.

Furthermore, setting the bounds `bounds = ([-np.infty, 0], [3, np.infty])` (that is q < 3 and beta > 0) allowed me to remove the weird line `if q >= 3: return 10000000`.