# Scipy curve fit (optimization) - vectorizing a conditional to identify threshold using a custom function

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to use `scipy curve_fit` to capture the value of **`a0` parameter. As of now, it is not changing (always comes out as 1)**:

```
X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
def func(X, a0, c):
     x1 = X[0]; x2 = X[1]
     a = x1*x2
     result = np.where(a(a<a0), -c*(a + np.sqrt(x2)), -c*x1)
     return result

Popt, Cov = scipy.curve_fit(func, X, y) 
a0, c = Popt
Predicted = func(X, a0, c) # a0 and c are constants
```

I get the values for c, which is a scalar, without any problem. I can't explain why `a0` (also a scalar) is always 1, and I am not sure how to fix it. I did see [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314699/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-cannot-fit-a-function-whose-return-value-depends-on-a-c) on SO that `np.where` can be used the way I have used it here, but apparently not for curve_fit function. Maybe I need to use a different method of optimization, and I'd like some pointers to do this using scipy methods.

Edit: I tried the construct suggested by Brad, but that's not it.

Comment: If I understand correctly the first parameter of `np.where` should be a boolean array the size of the array you want to insert things into. It is unclear from your snippet but I assume `a` is just an integer and `x` and `y` are integers unless your passing an array of arrays. Also `c` is not defined so I have to guess that it's a constant defined previously but that is the actual array you wanted changed.

Comment: I’m even more confused on the question than before. curve_fit works on continuous functions, but the function you’ve defined as I understand it is not continuous. It seems like you are trying to define a search function. Also as a side note for curve fit to optimize you would need to provide what the `y` array is. Maybe you could lay out the underlying problem you are trying to solve so it would be easier to follow along.

Comment: What is the value of ``y`` in your code when you do ``Popt, Cov = scipy.curve_fit(func, X, y)`` ? Also, I find a bit confusing that you have that external ``y``, but then inside your ``func`` you create another ``y`` from the second row of ``X``. Are these two ``y`` somehow related?

Comment: I have changed the name of the y inside the function to x2 and the x inside the function is now x1. The y in the argument is the target variable that can be anything, I'm making this up, say, y = [3, 5, 7].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated!

This should work. note that the `a` variable is a vector in this example of length 3 because it is computed by the element wise multiplication of the first and second elements of `X` which is a 2x3 matrix. Therefore `a0` can either be a scalar or a vector of length 3 and `c` can also be a scalar or a vector of length 3.

```
import numpy as np


X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

a0 = np.array([8,25,400])
# a0 = 2


# Code works whether C is scalar or a matrix since it can be broadcast to matrix a below.
# c = 3 # Uncomment this for scalar
c = np.array([8, 12, 2000])  # Element wise


def func(X, a0, c):
    x = X[0]
    y = X[1]
    a = x * y
    print(a.shape)
    result = np.where(a < a0, c * (a + np.sqrt(y)), c * x)
    return result


func(X, a0, c)
```

This is a minimum amount of code that works. Notice I removed the `y>0` and defined `a` to be the same size as `c`. Now you get the correct insertions because the first parameter of `np.where` is now the same size as the second and third parameters. Before  `(x<a) & (y>0)` always evaluated to `True` or `False` and that is a scalar in this context. If `a` was a N dimensional array you would have received a `ValueError` because the operands could not be broadcast together

```
import numpy as np


c = np.array([[22,34],[33,480]])


def func(X, a):
     x = X[0]; y = X[1]
     return np.where(c[(x<a)], -c*(a + np.sqrt(y)), -c*x)


X = [25, 600]
a = np.array([[2,14],[33,22]])

func(X,a)
```

This also works if `c` is a constant and `a` was the array you wanted manipulated

```
import numpy as np


c = 2


def func(X, a):
     x = X[0]; y = X[1]
     return np.where(a[(x<a)], -c*(a + np.sqrt(y)), -c*x)


X = [25, 600]
a = np.array([[2,14],[33,22]])

func(X,a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brad. Unfortunately this does not work. I clarified what c is and edited the question to make it more clear. My parameter of interest is a0, which always comes out as a constant (1) the way it is written now.

Comment: @SolomonVimal I still don't know what `c` is above. Is it a scalar or a matrix/ array?

Comment: c is a scalar, I will specify it also in the main question.

Comment: How do we pass the broadcast a0 into the curve-fitting function? My understanding is that curve_fit takes three required arguments: curve_fit(func, X, y), but the arguments of func are not explicitly passed in?

Comment: What does the function signature look like? Is it a custom function that you wrote or part of another package? or are you trying to optimize the function that was just created? In which case I'm very confused on what optimization would mean in that context.

Comment: The curve_fit function is part of scipy. The way I pass the func written here is popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, y), which then stores the parameters into popt.

Comment: I have clarified the variables. a in Brad's solution should be a0.